# Beginner questions about Qt

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, mfc, qt-creator

I want to ask some questions which I couldn't find in Qt's website.

1. Is Qt completely free or just some part of it, or not free at all?
2. Can I use its library in Visual Studio?
3. Can I use MFC with Qt together?
4. The main reason I want to use Qt is to create professional GUI's. What should I actually download? Qt Library, Qt Creator or both?

Comment: @LaszloPapp 1) [Not all licensing questions are off-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/are-licensing-questions-on-or-off-topic-on-so). Arguably this question relates to programming as the OP wants to know which parts of the library he can use for free in his code, and is not asking for legal advice *per se*. 2) I disagree, his questions are very clear - clear enough that two of us were able to independently give very similar answers. 3) Agreed, there are too many questions in one. 4) Agreed.

Comment: @JBentley: 1) Please first read carefully what you paste: "Also don't be surprised if the audience that finds your question feels that the legal issues outweigh the programming issues and decides to close it.". 2) Two of you giving similar answers do not mean it is clear for everyone at all. Also, people tend to answer to inappropriate questions as well, so this is hardly a reason to tell me it is unclear when I do not understand it. There could be a couple of issues I would think of, based on that question. Well, yes, one could say that is too broad instead of unclear.

Comment: Also, the most upvoted answer in there by the community: "Ask a lawyer, not a programmer. Asking a legal question on a site where the vast majority of visitors have had no formal training or experience in legal matters is asking an off-topic question. It is just as off topic as asking whether sitting in a chair for 8 hours a day while drinking lots of coffee is bad for your health. Even though that's pretty unique to the programmer profession too. Yes, finding a site where expert lawyers (or doctors) give advice for free might be difficult. They don't tick the same way we do.
"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It is available free under the LGPL license. [Click here](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html) to read the circumstances under which it can be used for free. Briefly - you can use it to produce proprietary / commercial software as long as you allow the user to modify / update the Qt dependencies. Typically this means dynamic linking but you can also statically link if you provide your users with the means to rebuild. You can also statically link if you are only going to use the software internally within your company (i.e. not distribute it).
2. Yes, and they have a Visual Studio plugin to make it easier.
3. Yes. Although it's hard to see why you would want to unless you're dealing with legacy code. MFC is outdated, awkward to use, and platform specific vs. Qt which is modern, easy to use, and cross platform.
4. It depends how you want to go about doing it. Just the library is fine if you are going to use it in your own IDE. Alternatively, you can use their IDE, which is Qt Creator, but that is optional. It's worth at least having Qt Designer, which is a tool for building GUIs visually. That is also optional, as you can hand code your GUIs if you wish.

Comment: @pepper The OP intents to implement a *professional GUI*. All of the points I made are very relevant for a professional project. Also, those are verifiable facts. There's more, still: Every little change in a QML file will trigger the MOC, and a full recompile of the entire GUI code. This gets **very** time consuming in larger projects.

Comment: @IInspectable this is the first time QML is mentioned, which is the most recent option on producing Qt GUIs, so this is being biased regarding a specific kind of Qt GUI. Also, there're several professional Qt based GUIs in the wide.

Comment: @IInspectable and, AFAIK, QML can be loaded at runtime.

Comment: @IInspectable Sure they can coexist - it depends how you use them. There's nothing to stop you designing a GUI in MFC for example, with a backend using the Qt library. As for professionalism - I refer you to [this Wikipedia list of software based on Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Software_that_uses_Qt). There are many large scale and recognizable names on that list.

Comment: You did not address the issue of false leak detection diagnostics when using MFC alongside Qt. As for professional GUIs: Many have tried, none have succeeded. Big names, like Firefox, VLC, or Perforce look ok, but do not properly behave.

Comment: With respect to false leak detection: That was one of the issues I pointed out in my initial comment. However, someone felt that the comment not only did not add anything substantial (which it did), but was also flag-worthy (for whatever reason). People apparently get touchy, when their favorite toy (Qt) is said to have issues (which it does).

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not sure what you mean about false leak detection (I did see your original comment, not sure why it was deleted). Why should it matter if MFC is used alongside some other library? I've never noticed any UI glitches in Firefox or VLC, personally.

Comment: @JBentley MFC performs leak detection when it is unloaded. If you add Qt (or really any library) into the mix, MFC may or may not be the last library to unload. This usually leads to false memory leak diagnostics (try it for yourself). If you want to experience how poor Qt keyboard interfaces are: Unplug your mouse, learn how to type fast, and compare how Qt applications compare to native GUIs. You will learn to identify Qt GUIs and you will learn to hate Qt GUIs.

Answer (score 3):

1. Qt is free (as in free speech and as in free beer): ["Qt is available under GPL v3, LGPL v2 and a commercial license"](http://qt-project.org/downloads).
2. yes, there's even a plugin (that **works for professional visual studio** versions).
3. Why? well anyway, through both libraries you can get native windows handles, so, it's one way of tampering with both at the same time, maybe. But, nor Qt or MFC is made to support one another.
4. Qt Library is what your source will be based on, Qt Creator is an IDE on its own, whether you'll use it or not for developing for Qt is an option. I myself use Vim and [recent versions of cmake](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/cmake-manual.html) instead of qmake when I can.